# Xslt Index vertically by two column (50 rows)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want create an index vertically by two columns, each column have 50 rows.

I created a simple vertically index (into one column) using this XSLT:

```
<span style="font-family:Univers Condensed; font-size:9pt; ">   
    <xsl:for-each select="//VICINITY[not(. = preceding::VICINITY)]">            
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:variable name ="localita" select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>....................</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="following::VICINITY[. = $localita][last()]">
                <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <br/>           
    </xsl:for-each>
</span>
```

This is my output :

ACCIAROLI...........2665.3 - 2666.5
AMENDOLARA..........3431.25
ANCONA..............3921.9
BRINDISI............3624
CASTELLAMMARE.......2573.5
CHIOGGIA............4108
CORIGLIANO CALABRO..3429.2 - 3429.55
FIUME TRIONTO.......3427
FRIGOLE.............3614.3
GENOVA..............1577

But I would a vertically index in a table divided in two column : (for this example I reduced the table to five rows)

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>ACCIAROLI.....2665.3 - 2666.5</td>      <td>CHIOGGIA............4108<br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
    <td>AMENDOLARA......3431.25</td>            <td>CORIGLIANO....3429.2-3429.55<br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>ANCONA............3921.9</td>           <td>FIUME TRIONTO.......3427<br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>BRINDISI...........3624</td>            <td>FRIGOLE.............3614.3<br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CASTELLAMMARE.....2573.5</td>           <td>GENOVA..............1577<br/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my XML:

```
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>              
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>2665.3</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>              
        <VICINITY>ACCIAROLI</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Secca Vecchia</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>              
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>              
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>2666.5</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        <VICINITY>ACCIAROLI</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Ondametro</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>              
        </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>              
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>3431.25</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        <VICINITY>AMENDOLARA</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Impianto di itticoltura;Boa "A"</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>              
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>3921.9</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>              
        <VICINITY>ANCONA</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Installazioni per idrocarburi;BARBARA H</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>              
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>              
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>3624</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>              
        <VICINITY>BRINDISI</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Brindisi-Casale (AERO)</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>          
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>              
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>2573.5</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        <VICINITY>CASTELLAMMARE DI STABIA</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Impianti di mitilicoltura;Boa SW</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>              
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>4108</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        <VICINITY>CHIOGGIA</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Diga N, estr</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>              
            <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>3429.2</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>              
            <VICINITY>CORIGLIANO CALABRO</VICINITY>
            <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Ingresso bacino di evoluzione;Molo S, estr</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
        </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>3429.55</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        <VICINITY>CORIGLIANO CALABRO</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Darsena N.2;Banchina N.4, spigolo S</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>3427</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        <VICINITY>FIUME TRIONTO</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Impianto di maricoltura</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>3614.3</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        <VICINITY>FRIGOLE</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Area di protezione e sviluppo delle risorse biologiche marine;Boa B3</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>          
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>              
        <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>1577</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
        <VICINITY>GENOVA</VICINITY>
        <ITA_LIGHT_NAME>Granarolo</ITA_LIGHT_NAME>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to do more than arranging the data into rows. It looks like you want to group them as well (because, for example, `ACCIAROLI` occurs twice, but you only want one row for that).

What you really need to look at is a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) here, as it is more efficient than constantly checking for preceding elements.

In your case, you would define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="prod_by_vicinity" match="NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT" use="VICINITY" />
```

I am grouping the `NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT` here, because it then makes it easier to get other values for the element other than `VICINITY`

You would then get the distinct `VICINITY` values, as follows:

```
 <xsl:variable name="distinct" select="//NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('prod_by_vicinity', VICINITY)[1])]" />
```

To start generating the rows, you only need to select the first 5 (or 50) nodes in this node-set (I've paramterised the number of rows here)

```
   <xsl:for-each select="$distinct[position() &lt;= $rows]">
```

To get the product in the first cell, and the product in the second cell in the row, you can just do this:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$distinct[$pos + $rows]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:param name="rows" select="5" />
   <xsl:key name="prod_by_vicinity" match="NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT" use="VICINITY" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="distinct" select="//NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('prod_by_vicinity', VICINITY)[1])]" />
     <table border="1">
       <xsl:for-each select="$distinct[position() &lt;= $rows]">
         <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
         <tr>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="$distinct[$pos + $rows]" />
         </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>      
     </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT">
      <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="VICINITY" />
         <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
         <xsl:for-each select="key('prod_by_vicinity', VICINITY)">
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1"> - </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER" />
         </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

NOTE: I have made a big assumption here. I have assumed the data is already sorted by `VICINITY` in the input XML. If it isn't, then it becomes more complicated, and you are probably looking at having to perform a two-pass transform to get it sorted before doing the above transform.

Comment: Dear Tim this dont give 2 column. Thanks .

Comment: I believe this does give two columns. I've added a border to the table to make it more clear. You can see it in action at http://www.xmlplayground.com/NTvfek

Comment: Ok Tim, I was wrong to enter the code in the correct position. Thanks.